# GWT cron job not running

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, cron

I'm creating a small web app. I have a cron job to sent out periodic emails from data stored in the database. However I don't think the cron job is running at all.

The files are here.
cron.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cronentries>
    <cron>
        <url>/cron/MailingServlet</url>
        <description>Put your Cron Job description here</description>
        <schedule>every 1 minutes</schedule>
    </cron>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>mailingService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.peter.from.cron.MailingServlet</servlet-class>   
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mailingService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/cron/MailingServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

</cronentries>
```

and the MailingServlet.java

```
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {

    _logger.info("CRON EXECUTED");
    List<Note> notes = new ArrayList<Note>();
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.getPersistenceManager();

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Query q = pm.newQuery(Note.class);
    q.setFilter("currentTime >= scheduledTime");
    q.declareParameters("long currentTime");

    try{
        notes =  (List<Note>) q.execute(now);
        for(Note n: notes){
            this.mail(n.getEmail(), n.getMessage());
            pm.deletePersistent(n);

        }

    }catch(Exception e){
        _logger.info(e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If the cron fires you will see it in the logs, is there anything there ? Is the cron job listed in the cron section of the dashboard ?

Comment: it is listed in the dashboard, in the logs there are many entries of `2014-05-21 10:23:27.936 /cron/MailingServlet 200 8ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine) module=default version=1
0.1.0.1 - - [21/May/2014:10:23:27 -0700] "GET /cron/MailingServlet HTTP/1.1" 200 0 - "AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)" "from.appspot.com" ms=8 cpu_ms=41 queue_name=__cron task_name=7bdbb6e6079794063fc7b417d96c1085 app_engine_release=1.9.5 instance=00c61b117cb5c40e76ca8ee8ddf811ffbe8ec846`

Comment: So the cron job is firing and your is running and returning a status 200.  So all looks well.  This means that if emails are not being sent, either your code is not sending them, or they are not being delivered.  Have you tried call the "/cron/MailingServlet" directly ?